# My script doesn't work because of Socket.io

Tags: html, node.js, socket.io

So, I have this problem. I was trying to add Socket.io, but it didn't work. I watched some tutorials but still, it doesnt work. Heres my code:

my java code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');

});
app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

serv.listen(2000);
console.log("Server Started");

var io = require('socket.io') (serv,{});
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("socket connection");
});
```

and this is my html:

```
hello!

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io();
</script>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include what you expect your script to do, how far through execution it gets, and what (if any) error messages you are getting.